# Unable to connect Android ADB over TCP/IP

Tags: wireless-networking, android, tcpip, android-studio, adb

I tried to connect to my phone through WiFi using Android ADB, but I can't connect it.

I tried this steps:

```
adb kill-server  
adb tcpip 5555  
adb connect 192.168.1.16:5555
```

And got this message:

> cannot connect to 192.168.1.16:5555: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond. (10060)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Your laptop and android device should be connected to the same Wifi network
2. You have USB driver installed.
   Details here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i was connected to `vpn` with a vnp client application like `Cisco AnyConnect`, i have just disconnected that and the problem has been fixed.

Comment: I have seen this as well, is there any way to make the ADB tcp/ip work while on VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your phone and other device is on same network and you are not connected to any VPN on device through which you are making the connection request.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and what I did at first was just turning off WiFi and turning it back on. It worked for me.